# Executar Selenium no Chrome de forma invisível (headless)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo um programa em Python 3.8 usando o Selenium e o Chromedrive,
para acessar um site pelo Google Chrome. Na hora de executar, o programa abre duas janelas, uma do
Google Chrome e outra do prompt. Porém, quero que esse acesso seja feito de forma invisível, sem
abrir nenhuma janela além da do Python.

Meu código está mais ou menos assim:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Como faço pra deixar o processo invisível pro usuário? 
Se eu tiver que instalar alguma biblioteca, em qual pasta do Python eu coloco ela? Qual o comando?

O programa vai ser executado no windows 32.

Obrigado desde já, preciso muito dessa ajuda.

Answer (score 7):

Para não exibir o navegador, você precisar criar uma `ChromeOptions` e adicionar o argumento `--headless=new` (para o novo modo de headless), se usar o modo implícito `--headless` o Chrome atualmente irá tratar como `--headless=old` (antigo modo de headless).

A mudança de `--headless` para `--headless=new` e `--headless=old` está [disponível desde o Chrome 112](https://Chrome%20112), se a sua versão do Chrome,  ou Chromium, for mais antiga use apenas `--headless`

Você não vai precisar instalar nenhuma biblioteca, pois a `ChromeOptions` está no `webdriver` do `selenium`, biblioteca a qual você já está utilizando.

Criando o `ChromeOptions` e a opção *headless*:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

Se estiver usando uma versão do Chrome/Chromium mais antiga que 112:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Agora com a variável `options` pronta, você precisa enviar a mesma no momento que for instanciar o driver do Chrome:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Seu código ficará da seguinte forma:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com")

#Restante do código

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel, salvou meu dia!!! Fiz isso e deu certo

Comment: Valeu cara!!!! Thank you so much

Comment: @DanielMendes tomei a liberdade de atualizar o código da API, e também a instrução sobre o argumento --headless, antes e depois do Chrome 112.

Answer (score 1):

Só para atualizar a resposta do Daniel.
Não precisa mais colocar:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Basta colocar:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Ou seja, tirando o "chrome_".

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Só pra atualizar a resposta do [GuyFawkes05th](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/540315/326451) Atualmente na biblioteca, precisa usar dessa forma: `options = ChromeOptions() options.add_argument("--headless=new") driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) driver.get('http://selenium.dev') driver.quit()` Fonte: [Headless is Going Away!](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/)

Comment: @Se77ings boa informação. Atualizei a resposta mais completa e objetiva: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440641/3635